# copy last 2 hours modified files from the folder using batch

Tags: batch-file

i want to copy files from the folder which was modified in last 2 hours.
kindly provide me the batch script. 
i have the folder name called E:folder1 and E:folder 2.
Folder1 will have more files and keep receiving in this folder.
i want to copy last 2 hours files only from folder 1 and paste it in folder.

Comment: do you know our [search box](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+copy+files+newer+than+hours) on the upper right corner?

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *"kindly provide me the batch script."*  == *"plz send teh codez"*.
**No.  Vote to Close**

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [FileTimeFilter.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/FileTimeFilterJS.bat)  :

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('filetimefiler.bat "E:\folder1" -hh -2') do (
   copy "%%~#" " E:\folder 2"
)
```